# how to use tax_query to apply both terms or one if one is empty

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, tax-query

I'm having trouble with getting tax_query to act as a filter for posts. What I would like is to have it so it will display cpt's that have the terms of county and status but also work if terms are not provided for status or county. So have the posts show if it has the term of "Adams" county in the County taxonomy and the the term of "Locked" in the Status taxonomy. But it needs to also work if a County is not provided, just a status and vice-versa.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => 5000,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => explode( ',', $st_term_final_string    )
            ),
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'County',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' =>  explode( ',', $il_term_final_string )
            )
        )
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Any hints to put me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with the following:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'posts_per_page' => 5000,
);

$statuses = explode( ',', $st_term_final_string);
$terms = explode( ',', $il_term_final_string );

if ( $statuses || $terms ) {
  $args['tax_query'] = array();
  if ( $statuses ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'Status',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $statuses
    );
  }

  if ( $terms ) {
   $args['tax_query'][] = array(
     'taxonomy' => 'County',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => $terms
    );
  }

  if ( $statuses && $terms ) $args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  // do your stuff here

} else {

  // You have no statuses nor county, I don't know what you want to do in this case

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried variations of this along with what you posted but I can't get it to work. Just to test, I tried echoing out "testing" and I put it in each condition and it shows no matter what. Not sure what I might have missed.

Comment: have you tried to `var_dump( explode(',', $st_term_final_string) );` and `$il_term_final_string` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried those and they are showing the correct data. I'm just not seeing anything when it loops through with the $args.

Comment: Got it working. I had an issue that was being caused by some code that was not posted. Thanks!